# WPF document viewer page size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, documentviewer

How to set page size for WPF document viewer in cm mm?

Comment: you should use pixels. If you set it to cm/mm then it depends on what resolution you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1cm = 37.8 Device Independent Pixels. Because in WPF, you calculate in DIP (Device independent Pixels), this value is constant, you can rely on it. Therefore you can multiply your cm-value with 37.8 and you get the value your looking for.
For completness: 96DIP = 1inch;